# spring boot security allow post request but only with permission

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

So my problem is a little different from the rest of the spring boot questions. I want to allow post requests in my security config but only with authentication

here is my config file:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
```

thanks for helping ;)

Comment: And what about GET and all other requests?

Comment: Get request are valid. but I guess the crsf or something is blocking the post

Comment: yes, but I am not shure if this is the tipical way of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [antMachers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html) with the following pattern.

```
antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST)
```

if you want to authenticate POST method of only certainpath

```
antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/path")
```